# How can download android 2.1 platform

Tags: android

I have already installed android 2.2 and now i want to test my application on the android 2.1 platform..
So for that how can i download and install android 2.1 without any change in my current running android 2.2 platform..
Please help me..

Comment: on phone or on emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GoTo the folder where you installed **android-sdk**...and Open **Sdk-manager** !!

after that goto **Available-Packages** and download versions of android.

hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your **Android SDK and AVD**
   Manager.
2. Go to **Virtual Devices -> New**
3. Choose your **Target** platform

[image]